# Download citation count to include in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I am using LaTeX and biblatex for my CV. I would like a little bit of magic to automatically fetch citation counts of my publications from [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/) and stick it into the references in my publication list. I think it is probably best to modify the BibTeX file before running LaTeX/Biber, but I am looking for suggestions. I apologize if this is off topic.

Although Scopus requires a subscription, from work, however, I can access the information I want without providing log in information.

From Scopus I can download citations that look like:

```
@ARTICLE{Richards2011883,
  note={cited By (since 1996) 0},
  url={http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-80052470808&partnerID=40&md5=adbc461770e11f0760e8cfe3c2ce6f93},
}
```

I would need to combine the citations from Scopus with the one in my bib file. Although I prefer using a different key format from the one Scopus uses, I would be willing to change. I would also need to scrap the citation count from the note field. Finally, I would need to find a way to automate the download process. The subscription aspect makes answering this one difficult.

Comment: Do you have to be logged into Scopus to retrieve citation counts?

Comment: This seems off topic to me. It looks like the "little bit of magic" that you're after will be some snippet of `python` code or some such, which you will just call with `\write18` from inside your document.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, no, I can get to the information I need from Scopus without having to log in.

Comment: @Seamus, it might be a little off topic. I would be happy to accept an answer as to why LaTeX and friends is a bad way to do what I want. I could write a non-LaTeX script to parse my bib file, find the info I need (e.g., DOI), fetch the info I want from Scopus, and jam it back into the bib file. I am not sure why I would use `\write18` in this case. My thoughts were that Biber is already parsing the bib file and I thought there might be a LaTeX/Biber/BibTeX solution.

Comment: At the moment, Biber can perform regular expressions on a bibliography source (including remote ones), but as far as I know it must work with a recognized format. Does Scopus yield citation counts for each citation within its (non-standard) BibTeX or RIS etc. entry?

Comment: I think that this is potentially on topic, but I'll need to see what format the citation counts come in. @DanielE.Shub, Could you place a link to a sample please?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, Yes, Scopus provides citation counts in the bib entry (see edit).

Comment: Excellent. Is the URL easy to produce? Biber can be asked to grab a BibTeX library from a remote source, such as Scopus, and using the regular expressions perhaps something can be done with the note field.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, The URLs are easy to generate.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `bashful` package; combined with wget and some script wizardry, you should be able to do it.